# Watermark strategy not working for Kafka Consumer in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm new working with Flink, so there are some problems I'm facing when defining watermarks in Flink.

Let's start with the Kafka Consumer. The deserialization used is **JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema**, so there is no customized parse.

```
val kafkaConsumer: FlinkKafkaConsumer[ObjectNode] = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[ObjectNode](
  kafkaTopic,
  new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false),
  properties
)
```

If a sink is applied to this code, it works just fine. The problem is that a watermark is needed to avoid out of order events. That's the strategy I wrote:

```
 val watermarkStrategy: WatermarkStrategy[ObjectNode] = WatermarkStrategy
  .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[ObjectNode](Duration.ofSeconds(100))
  .withTimestampAssigner(
    new SerializableTimestampAssigner[ObjectNode] {
      override def extractTimestamp(record: ObjectNode, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
        Instant.parse(record.get("value").get("content").get("timestamp").asText()).getEpochSecond
      }
    })
```

I ended up with this code after doing some research, but this is not working. These are my questions:

- Using ObjectNode the best option here? Is there any other option?
- The field **timestamp** is a string in the ISO 8601 standard, so I have to parse it to a long. Is this the best way to do that? Is there a better way?
- Are SerializableTimestampAssigner and forBoundedOutOfOrderness the right things to use?

Comment: What's going wrong? How do you know it's not working? Also, how are you applying the watermark strategy (are you calling it on the FlinkKafkaConsumer, or on the stream it produces)? Furthermore, using watermarks won't prevent out-of-order events, but it will prevent timers from firing prematurely. Depending on what your pipeline is doing, you may not need watermarks.

Comment: I found out the error. It was my parse. But I set this watermark in the **assignTimestampsAndWatermarks** of the kafka consumer that I showed in the first code block. About watermark, can you explain in details? I always thought that Watermarks are needed for event-based aggregation to cut off late events, and that's my case. I will connect two streams, do some aggregation and I want to limit how late those events can be. Is that wrong?

Comment: That sounds right. You want to limit how long you wait for the out-of-orderness to resolve itself. There's some good background material here -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/streaming_analytics.html -- if you want to read more.

Comment: Thank you David. By the way, what is the best option to cast a string to unix timestamp in Flink? This kind of thing is easier in Spark (at least it is easier to search about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my parse.

```
dateFormat.parse(record.get("value").get("content").get("timestamp").asText()).getTime
```